# How to replace following active record query with association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have developed rails sample app.Here i have made a scope 
  **named_scope :from_users_followed_by, lambda { |user| followed_by(user) }**

```
def self.followed_by(user)
  followed_ids = %(SELECT followed_id FROM relationships WHERE follower_id = :user_id) { :conditions => ["user_id IN (#{followed_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", { :user_id => user }] }
end
```

This scope is responsible for feed of microposts in user home page.
Now I have been asked to write this scope with Association.So please help me .

Comment: can you add your models and relationship among them

Comment: Before reading, The first thing I wanted was to edit your post. Please edit, this could be a good question.

Comment: This could help a lot http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

This is well explained in this chapter of Michael Hartl's tutorial: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users

Basically you want a model for following, a join model, and a has_many :through relationship to connect the pieces.